# Make a div appear only when needed

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a  as an alert bar on my page. I have a logout message appearing after the user logs out. But the div shows up all the time. I want it to show up only once the user logs out.

my code is as such that makes the div read the message

```
    <?php

if ($_GET['msg'])
{
       echo '<div id="success_message">' . base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['msg'])) . '</div>';

}
?>
```

I figure we could add something to this code to make it appear after the page is visited after the logout. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd approach it from the other way - i.e, rather than responding to a message that says the user is logged out, I would always show the div ***unless*** the user is logged in. That's the approach I use to handling a request for a page that the user must be logged-on to access. If the user isn't logged on, then the request is redirected to login.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
if(isset($_GET["msg"]))
{
echo '<div id="success_message">' . base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['msg'])) . '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
  ...
}
```

And you should set it somewhere before this code just after user logs out.

Answer (score 0):

`if($_GET['var'])` isn't valid anymore.

Try to use the function `'isset'` to verify the existence of the string.

```
if(isset($_GET['param'])) {
   // ...
}
```